# Get last accessed timestamp value of a user in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Im trying to display the last accessed field when a user logs in. For this I tried using User::getLastLoginTime() . But this returns a fatal error saying

**PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\customize_block\Plugin\Block\ContractDetails::get() in /var/www/html/core/modules/user/src/Entity/User.php on line 265**

Here is my block ,in my custom module:

```
/**
 * Provides a 'Customized contract' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "customer_info",
 *   label = @Translation("Customer and contract info"),
 *   module = "user",
 *   context = {
 *     "current_user" = @ContextDefinition("entity:user", label = @Translation("Current User"))
 *   }
 * )
namespace Drupal\customize_block\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

class ContractInfo extends BlockBase {
 public function build() {
 $output='';
 global $base_url;
 $current_user = $this->getContext('current_user');
 $output.='<div>' . $current_user -> contextData . '</div>';

     return array(
      '#markup' => $output,
      '#cache' => array(
     'contexts' => array('url'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Am I calling this method correct way?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not. You need some specific user, for example the current user or some other user object. To do it for the current user, it looks like this:

```
\Drupal::currentUser()->getLastAccessedTime();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Frank, using `Drupal::currentUser` inside the blocks is not recommended to tightly couple it. I'm trying to use **Context system** as blocks extend **ContextAwarePluginBase** (please look the updated code above.) Now, the problem is that the _user_ properties are protected here. How can I use getters on the AccountInterface so that I can access its **getLastAccessedTime()**

Comment: Well, I don't see a problem here, just search for "\Drupal::currentUser()" in the Drupal core, it's used just about everywhere. So if it's good enough for core, it's good enough for me :-) But if you find a working way with the contexts, I would be interested in seeing the approach! Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @frank, using context inside blocks almost works. The above code, `$current_user` has the entire user related details. Im not able to access it though as its private. Do you know a way to access the private properties .

Comment: I tried it the way you describe, but all I get is a context object (getContext). I have no idea how to get the user object from that one.